# Php no funciona en hosting pero si en localhost

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, localhost

Tengo este código que en localhost funciona perfectamente, que recibe los datos enviados mediante un formulario y saca los resultados mediante una tabla que se rellena automáticamente según los datos enviados:

```
<table width="1024px" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" id=tabla class="table_compare">
            <?php

                if(isset($_POST['destino'])){
                    $codigos=array_merge([$_POST['codigo_uno']],$_POST['destino']);
                    $etiquetas=getEtiquetas($ConUsuarios,$codigos);
                    $txt=null;
                    //$txt.='<table>';
                    foreach(tabla_pvt($ConUsuarios,$codigos) as $i=>$r){
                        if(!$i){
                            $txt.='<thead>';
                            $txt.='<tr>';
                            foreach($r as $campo=>$dato)  if(!in_array($campo,[
                                'RT','entryNumber',                     
                            ]))
                                if($campo=='compuesto') $txt.='<th></th>';
                                else{
                                    if(isset($etiquetas[$campo]))
                                        $txt.='<th class="centrar UPPER"><div>'.$etiquetas[$campo].'</div><div>'.str_replace('c_','',$campo).'</th>';
                                    else
                                        $txt.='<th class="centrar">'.$campo.'</th>';
                                }
                            $txt.='</tr>';
                            $txt.='</thead>';
                            $txt.='<tr>';
                            foreach($r as $campo=>$dato)  if(!in_array($campo,[
                                'RT','entryNumber',                     
                            ])) 
                                if($campo=='compuesto') $txt.='<td class="fondo">Component</td>';
                                else $txt.='<td class="fondo centrar">%</td>';
                            $txt.='</tr>';                      
                        }
                        $txt.='<tr>';
                        foreach($r as $campo=>$dato) if(!in_array($campo,[
                            'RT','entryNumber',                     
                        ]))
                            $txt.='<td class="centrar">'.$dato.'</td>';
                        $txt.='</tr>';
                    }
                    //$txt.='</table>';
                    echo $txt;
                }
                function getEtiquetas($conn,$cods){
                    $rs=mysql_query("
                        SELECT codigo,producto FROM raw_material;
                    ",$conn);
                    while($rsi=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
                        $r['c_'.$rsi['codigo']]=$rsi['producto'];
                    return $r;
                }
                function tabla_pvt($conn,$codigos){
                    $cols=null;
                    foreach($codigos as $c)
                        $cols.=",SUM(IF(codigo='".$c."',porcentaje,NULL)) c_".$c;
                    $rs=mysql_query("
                        SELECT * FROM (
                            SELECT RT,entryNumber,compuesto
                              FROM composicion
                              GROUP BY 2
                          ) c2 JOIN (
                            SELECT entryNumber
                              ".$cols."
                              FROM (
                                SELECT DISTINCT entryNumber,codigo,porcentaje
                                  FROM composicion 
                                  JOIN raw_material USING(materiaprimaID)
                                  WHERE codigo IN (".implode(',',$codigos).")  
                              ) c1 GROUP BY 1
                          ) c3 USING(entryNumber)
                          ORDER BY RT;
                    ",$conn);
                    $r=[];
                    while($ri=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) $r[]=$ri;
                    return $r;
                }               
            ?>  
            </table>
```

Resulta que cuando lo subo al servidor (hosting) no funciona y no da ningún tipo de error, simplemente no dibuja la tabla. Adjunto captura de pantalla.
El diseño se a realizado mediante dreamweaver con configuración php 5.6, el servidor también lo he configurado para php 5.6 por lo tanto no entiendo que está pasando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que esta ocurriendo en el hosting?

Seleccionado desde cpanel la versión de php 5.4 es cuando la página me sale en blanco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si selecciono otra versión de php obtengo el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en el log de error del servidor web? ¿Qué diferencia hay entra la versión local y la del servidor? ¿Ambas contienen los datos en sus bases de datos correspondientes? Por último, ya que estás empezando a desarrollar en PHP, **NO USES LAS FUNCIONES `mysql_*`**. Procura usar PDO/MySQL o bien mysqli.

Comment: Disculpa pero estoy muy verde, ¿donde puedo ver el log de error del servidor? y como miro la diferencia entre la versión local y la del servidor?

Comment: En el panel de control de tu alojamiento deberías tener acceso a los logs de acceso y de error del servidor web. Si no, deberías activar (durante el proceso de desarrollo) la salida de mensajes de error y advertencia al navegador. En cuanto a la diferencia, imagino que has cambiado los parámetros de conexión a la base de datos, ¿no?

Comment: si son imagenes publicalas editando la pregunta. si es texto copialo como tal (dale formato, que tenemos un mini-editor estupendo para ello).

Comment: editada la pregunta.

Comment: Tal vez suene a pregunta tonta pero, ¿la DB de MySQL está en el mismo servidor cierto?, ¿si haces las mismas consultas (en PHPMyAdmin, por ejemplo) la consulta te muestra resultados?

Comment: En localhost funciona porque la versión de PHP que tienes instalada es más antigua y aún soporta el mysql. Las versiones más modernas, como la del hosting, requieren mysqli y por eso sale el error del último pantallazo. No es difícil de arreglear, solamente hay que cambiar de unas funciones a otras. Aunque cambia el orden de los parámetros y resulta un poco confuso, pero nada más.

Comment: @RaúlGómez, el error que se ve en la ultima captura te esta diciendo que `$conn` es bool, y eso pasa cuando no se pudo conectar a la DB, es decir, tu problema seguramente se deba que no te estas pudiendo conectar a la DB

Comment: En primer lugar, puedes ver en la primera advertencia que te están recomendando lo mismo que te recomendé yo: usar PDO o mysqli en lugar de las funciones mysql_*. En segundo lugar, @RaúlGómez **casi** tiene razón, pero el problema real es que la consulta SQL que hiciste con `mysql_query()` ha fallado y, por ello, devuelve `false`. Para ver qué problema has tenido con la consulta deberías blindar el código ante errores. Si compartes la zona del `mysql_connect()` y el `mysql_select_db()` podría ayudarte a blindar ambas funciones y, además, convertirlo a mysqli o PDO (lo que prefieras).

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia, ya he transformado todo el proyecto a mysqli, efectivamente era ese el problema. ya no tengo problemas con el servidor. Ya tengo la web operativa y online. Muchas gracias a todos por darme con la solución.